# Angular HttpClient return boolean

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to have a return boolean value based on conditions when I call my API that return an object, but I can't figure out how to do it because I get every time a subscription...

This is my code on component.ts:

```
    result(){
       return checkPiva()
    }
    checkPiva(){
        return this._mysrvUsers.getUserByPIVA('858585847');
    }
```

and this is my code on service.ts:

```
        getUserByPIVA(piva: string){
        const currentResellerCode = localStorage.getItem('resellercode')
        const url = env.apiUrl + "endUser/partitaIva?pi="+piva
        return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(map(res=>{
            if(res){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }))

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to return `boolean` value instead `Observable<boolean>`?

Comment: Yes, i want to return a boolean value

Comment: Closest to what you want may be to use `.toPromise()` and then use async/await, or otherwise use callbacks.

Comment: .toPromise() is decrypted !

Answer (score 1):

You should really adopt rxjs and reactive principles if you're to use Angular. It can feel overwhelming at first, but it's for the better.

service:

```
getFoo() {
   return this.http.get('/foo').pipe(map(res => !!res));
}
```

component:

```
getFoo() {
   return this.service.getFoo()
      .subscribe(hasFoo => {
         this.result = hasFoo;
      });
}
```

html:

```
<button (click)="getFoo()">clickme</button>
<pre>result={{hasFoo}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

RxJS has a function which will transform an Observable into a Promise `firstValueFrom`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { firstValueFrom, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FakeService {
  /* get random true or false boolean mocked */
  getBool(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(Boolean((Math.random() * 2) | 0));
  }

  getBoolAsPromise(): Promise<boolean> {
    return firstValueFrom(this.getBool());
  }
}
```

In your consumer:

```js
export class SomeComponentClass {

  constructor(private fs: FakeService) {}
  
  async getBool() {
    const bool = await this.fs.getBoolAsPromise();
    console.log(bool);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your **getUserByPIVA** function is returning `Observable<boolean>` and you cant return a `boolean` from it.
You can `subscribe` this observable wherever you want and it's the **best way** or if you want to achieve `Synchronous` behaviour using it then you can use `async` `await` to achieve this.

In order to use `async-await` you need to convert `Observable` into `promise`.For that you can use `RxJS 7+` `lastValueFrom` or `toPromise`

```ts
async useItLike(){
    let result = await lastValueFrom(this._mysrvUsers.getUserByPIVA('858585847'));
    console.log(result); // will print true/false
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The request returns an observable so in order to get the value and use it right away you have to convert it to a promise:

```js
getUserByPIVA(piva: string){
    const currentResellerCode = localStorage.getItem('resellercode');
    const url = env.apiUrl + "endUser/partitaIva?pi="+piva;
    return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(map(res => !!res));
}

async result(){
   return await checkPiva();
}

async checkPiva(){
  return await this._mysrvUsers.getUserByPIVA('858585847').toPromise();
}
```

And you have to `const res = await result();` wherever you are calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I solved my problem by doing this:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){
        this.validateAsyncPiva = this.validateAsyncPiva.bind(this);
    }

    validateAsyncPiva(params:any){
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject)=>{
            const currentResellerCode = localStorage.getItem('resellerCode')
            const url = env.apiUrl + "endUser/partitaIva?pi="+params.value
            this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe({
                next:(res:any)=>{
                    if(res.length<=0){
                    resolve()
                    }
                    else if(res[0].resellerCode == currentResellerCode) {
                        reject('User is already on your list')
                    }else if(res[0].resellerCode != currentResellerCode){
                        reject('User is taken by another RESELLER')
                    }else{
                        resolve()
                    }
                },
                error: (err:any)=>{
                    console.log(err);
                    reject("Cannot contact validation server");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```